# App showing DialogFragment crashes after rotation

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

When I rotate my device while showing a DialogFragment, my app crashes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp, PID: 27909
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.myapp/com.myapp.FileListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4495)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:201)
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:167)
    at com.myapp.ActionsDialogFragment.onDestroy(ActionsDialogFragment.java:127)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:2202)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1196)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:2083)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:244)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:368)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:203)
    at com.myapp.FileListActivity.onDestroy(FileListActivity.java:1106)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6881)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4190)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4221) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4495) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

That's my DialogFragment:

```
public class ActionsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public interface ActionsDialogListener {
        void onActionSelected(DialogFragment dialog, int position);
    }

    AlertDialog dialog;
    ActionsDialogListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (ActionsDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement ActionsDialogListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actions_dialog, container, false);

        CustomListAdapter cla;
        cla = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity());
        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewActions);
        final AlertDialog finalDialog = dialog;
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mListener.onActionSelected((DialogFragment) getParentFragment(), position);
                Log.d(FileListActivity.TAG, "Dismissing dialog");
//                ActionsDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
                finalDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        list.setAdapter(cla);
        dialog.setView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(FileListActivity.TAG, "ActionDialogFragment onDestroy()");
        dismiss();
//        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    ...
    }

}
```

The error says "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState". But I don't know where the InstanceState is being saved. For me it's okay to dismiss the dialog and recreate it after the rotation.

Any idea what's going wrong?

EDIT:

My DialogFragment is created in the main activity like that:

```
void showActionsDialog() {
    actionsDialog = new ActionsDialogFragment();
    actionsDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ActionsDialogFragment");
}
```

EDIT 2:

Just in case it's important. That's my main activity's `onDestroy()` method:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "FileListActivity onDestroy()");
    if (exifReadingDialog != null) { exifReadingDialog.dismiss(); }
    dataFragment.mRetainedCache = mMemoryCache;
    dataFragment.setData(mediaFolder);
}
```

EDIT 3:

Some additional thoughts: Many people here at stackoverflow say you should use either `onCreateDialog` or `onCreateView` in a `DialogFragment`. Maybe that's my problem. But if I remove `onCreateDialog` and the `dialog` variable, dismissing doesn't work anymore. So far I'm using this solution: [Cannot get DialogFragment to dismiss programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738572/cannot-get-dialogfragment-to-dismiss-programatically) (just for dismissing the dialog, but crashing on rotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I have tried a lot of things. I changed my `ActionsDialogFragment` to look more like in [this tutorial](http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/06/android-dialogfragment-containing-listview.html).

But I think that the real error was in my custom `ListAdapter`. I changed this part

```
public @NonNull View getView(int position, View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(null);
```

to

```
public @NonNull View getView(int position, View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
```

Now I can dismiss the `DialogFragment` by a simple `dismiss();` and the app doesn't crash anymore after rotation.

So I should have posted the complete class in my question. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You get Leaked Window exception because `Alert dialog` is running while Your activity is destroyed. you should dismiss dialog when activity is destroyed

try this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    try {
        if (dialog!= null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Also in your `setOnItemClickListener` dismiss the dialog first

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (finalDialog != null && finalDialog.isShowing()) {
                  finalDialog.dismiss();
             }
            mListener.onActionSelected((DialogFragment) getParentFragment(), position);
            Log.d(FileListActivity.TAG, "Dismissing dialog");
    //      ActionsDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no `FragmentTransaction.commit()` in my code. I have added the function creating my DialogFragment to my question. I have tried to change `dismiss();` to `dismissAllowingStateLoss();` but without success. If I use your example code instead of `actionsDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ActionsDialogFragment");` from my code, the app still crashes with a similar error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.myApp/com.myApp.FileListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed`.

Comment: I have tried that (it's almost the same I tried before) and it gives me the error from my last comment. I guess the problem is now that my `ActionsDialogFragment` is being dismissed in its `onDestroy()` method. If I remove `dismissAllowingStateLoss();`, I get the error from the comment to FrankMonza's answer ("Activity has leaked window").

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I changed my code but I still get that WindowLeaked error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem si that onDestroy calls a Fragment transaction commit on parent activity and this cannot be done after onSavedInstance has been called and that is done before onDestroy. Do you really need to dismiss onDestroy()??

Comment: If I don't dismiss, I get this error: `E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.myApp.FileListActivity has leaked window DecorView@2b05e78[] that was originally added here`

Comment: Then do it onPause and not onDestroy

Comment: Do you mean `public void onPause() { super.onPause(); dismissAllowingStateLoss(); }` in `ActionsDialogFragment`? Same error!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Don't dismiss it inside onDestroy(). Do it inside onPause(). I hope this helps!

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    dismiss();
}
```