# Dealing with Progress dialog and screen orientation on robospice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, robospice

I receive this exception while change screen orientation in case showing progress dialog:

```
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734): Activity com.org.scgroup.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43cf9838 that was originally added here
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.org.scgroup.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43cf9838 that was originally added here
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:227)
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at com.org.scgroup.MainActivity.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:253)
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at com.org.scgroup.BookFragment.downloadBook(BookFragment.java:125)
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at com.org.scgroup.BookFragment$1.onClick(BookFragment.java:255)
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
 08-25 06:03:06.482: E/WindowManager(734):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
```

I have tried many ways like AsyncTask does but they can't work. [**Here**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) is one of them.
What I want to do is showing progress dialog when download data from fragment. Here is my try:
**The fragment**

```
 static interface TaskCallbacks {
    void onPreExecute();
    void onProgressUpdate(int percent);
    void onPostExecute();
    void onError();
    void reset();
}  
private class DownloadListener extends AbstractNotify<List<Entry>>{
    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException arg0) {
        Ln.e(arg0);
        isDownloading = false;
        mCallbacks.onError();
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestProgressUpdate(RequestProgress progress) {
        mCallbacks.onProgressUpdate((int)progress.getProgress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(List<Entry> result) {
        Ln.d("total download %d files", result.size());
        isDownloading = false;
        mCallbacks.onPostExecute();
    }
}

 //Execute the download request
 getSpiceManager().excute(request, new DownloadListener());

 @Override
public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Ln.d("onAttach activity");
    mCallbacks = (TaskCallbacks) activity;

};

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}
```

**The activity**

```
    class BaseActivity implements TaskCallbacks{ 
    @Override   
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   // try to reshow dialog 
  if(null != savedInstanceState){
        isDownloading = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IS_DOWNLOADING);
        currentProgress = savedInstanceState.getInt(CURRENT_PROGRESS);
        downloadDialog.setProgress(currentProgress);    
        if(isDownloading){
            downloadDialog.show();
        }

} 
 }

 @Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    if(null != downloadDialog){
        downloadDialog.show();
    }       
    isDownloading = true;
}
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(int percent) {
    downloadDialog.incrementProgressBy(percent);

}
@Override
public void onPostExecute() {
    if(null != downloadDialog && downloadDialog.isShowing()){
        downloadDialog.setProgress(100);
        downloadDialog.dismiss();
    }

    isDownloading = false;
}
@Override
public void onError() {
    if(null != downloadDialog && downloadDialog.isShowing()){
        downloadDialog.dismiss();
    }

    isDownloading = false;  
}
}
```

I have no idea why this approach worked fine for asynctask but `robospice` doesn't.  Am I missing something? 
**P/S**: set `android:configChanges` in manifest or disable screen orientation maybe work but I don't want to use these approach. So, please tell me where I am wrong or give me a workable example with progress dialog using `robospice`. Thanks in advance!

**Update**
As **Snicolas** recommend, I tried to use `DialogFragments`, there is no exception, but when screen orientation changed while executing request, the dialog stop updating progress, it always showing and I can't dismiss it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not related to RoboSpice per say. You should not use a Dialog, as it may leak its window... As it is in your case :)

It's quite difficult to do it well. That's why Google introduced DialogFragments. As you will see in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), DialogFragments are quite easy to use, you will basically wrap a dialog inside a Fragment.

This way, the FragmentManager will manage the life cycle of the dialog in pace with the life cycle of the activity.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I have tried to use `DialogFragments` but it give me the same problem.

Comment: You can't have the same error with DialogFragments. Please update your code or ask a new question with this code.

Comment: Sorry for update late, there is no exception, but when screen orientation changed while executing request, the dialog stop updating progress, it always showing and I can't dismiss it.

Comment: You may always add your fragment to your fragmentmanager during onResume/onStart. But you should only add it if it's not already known of your fragment manager. Here is an example : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11202084/693752

Comment: I figure out not only the dialog's issue, but also the `onRequestSuccess` in robopsice listener can't notify the view. For example, when activity recreate, the request continue execute in background, but it can't call dismiss dialog or update data for listview. I also try to attach and detach activity like above but doesn't work. Hope you can help me again.

Comment: You need to re-plug a new listener to a pending request when your device rotates. Use addListenerIfPending in your SpiceManager, you will see it accepts a more detailed listener that can be notified when a request was pending and you could replug to it.

Answer (score -3):

**Try This**

```
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|fontScale"
```

add these line in your Manifest.xml

Comment: As I said, I don't want to use this approach cause it is a bad practice. You can see my given link above. Another reason is I have to make 2 manifest files: one for android 3.0 and above, one for older version.