# FragmentManager Not Removing Dynamically added Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am trying to add/remove `DialogFragments` to/from my `FragmentManager` dynamically as a user performs different actions. The problem is that the `FragmentManager` is not properly removing all of them. I am calling the `remove()` function, so I am curious as to why these `Fragments` are not being removed. I have searched online, and the remove method is what people say you should use in order to remove `Fragments` from the `FragmentManager`.

Example Code below showing what I am doing:

```
            // originally added `LoginRestFragment` with TAG_LOGIN_REST_FRAGMENT tag to Fragment Manager
            rest = new SettingsDialogFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            rest.setArguments(bundle);
            Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_LOGIN_REST_FRAGMENT);
            Log.d("frag_type", fragment.toString());
            fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_LOGIN_REST_FRAGMENT);
            Log.d("is_frag_removed", fragment.toString());
            // why does this return a Fragment type ^^ shouldn't it throw null errror?
            Log.d("rest", rest.toString());
            // ^ this shows rest has been updated from LoginRestFrament to SettingsDialogFragment
            fm.beginTransaction().add(rest, TAG_LOGIN_REST_FRAGMENT).commit();
            fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_LOGIN_REST_FRAGMENT);
            Log.d("frag_type", fragment.toString());
            // why is this not SettingsDialogFragment??
```

Log Statements showing what is represented. I should note that what is shown on the screen is no longer the LoginRestFragment, but the `SettingsDialogFragment` (as is expected), and rest is a class variable.

```
D/frag_type: LoginRestFragment
D/is_frag_removed: LoginRestFragment
D/rest: SettingsDialogFragment
D/frag_type: LoginRestFragment
```

Comment: I believe you have to wait for a UI thread cycle to finish before the commits actually go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you DeeV! What you said is true, and it is how I found a workaround to solve this that is answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246479/android-fragmenttransaction-commit-when) StackOverflow entry. You can essentially just use `executePendingTransactions()`  on your `FragmentManager` to make commits dynamically.