# Android app keeps showing "App isn't Responding" error

Tags: android, performance, androidx

I recently migrated to **androidX** for developing my app.But when I run the app on my device ,it always shows "App isn't responding" error message. I have just added the drawer activity and two fragments to it. When I run the app, it lags continuously.Even the sliding of drawer takes much time and also when I click the button on the fragment ,it's click event is responding after long time.Don't know what exactly is going wrong.My other projects, which use support library, aren't lagging although they contain much more than just 2 fragments.Thanks for any help.

My drawer activity code

```
public class DrawerActivity extends MAWBaseActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

DrawerLayout drawer;
NavigationView navigationView;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
FrameLayout logNWorkContainer;
ImageView ivUserImage;
TextView tvUserName;
TextView tvUserDesignation;
TextView tvUserCode;
View navHeader;
LinearLayout activityProgressLayout;
ProgressBar activityProgress;

/**
 * Intent
 *
 * @param context calling activity context
 */
public static void show(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DrawerActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    logNWorkContainer = findViewById(R.id.logNWorkContainer);
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    activityProgressLayout = findViewById(R.id.activityProgressLayout);
    activityProgress = findViewById(R.id.activityProgress);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Navigation view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    ivUserImage = navHeader.findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
    tvUserName = navHeader.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvUserDesignation = navHeader.findViewById(R.id.tvUserDesignation);
    tvUserCode = navHeader.findViewById(R.id.tvUserCode);

    UserData userData = UserCache.user().getUserData();
    if (userData == null) {
        Login.show(this);
        finish();
    }
    if (userData != null) {
        // getNotificationAPICall(userData);
        String name = ifNullReplace(userData.getFirstName(), EMPTY) + " " + ifNullReplace(userData
                .getLastName(), EMPTY);
        tvUserName.setText(name);
        if (userData.getCode() == null) {
            tvUserCode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            tvUserCode.setText("Emp No :- " + userData.getCode());
        }

        if (userData.getUserDesignation() == null || userData.getUserDesignation().equalsIgnoreCase(EMPTY)) {
            tvUserDesignation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            tvUserDesignation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvUserDesignation.setText(ifNullReplace(userData.getUserDesignation(), EMPTY));
        }

        ivUserImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_user_new);
        String url = UrlConstant.GET_THUMB_BY_NAME + userData.getPhoto() + UrlConstant.SIZE_100 + UrlConstant.IMAGE_USER;
        UIUtils.loadRoundImage(url, ivUserImage, R.drawable.ic_profile_small);
    }

    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    beginFragmentTransaction(homeFragment, "Home");

}

/**
 * Begin fragment transaction
 *
 * @param fragment fragment
 * @param name     name of menu
 */
public void beginFragmentTransaction(Fragment fragment, String name) {

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(name);

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.logNWorkContainer, fragment).commit();
}

/**
 * Get activity progress
 *
 * @return progressbar
 */
public ProgressBar getActivityProgress() {
    return activityProgress;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        Dialogs.getInstance().showExitDialog(DrawerActivity.this);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_notifications) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.menu_home) {

        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        beginFragmentTransaction(homeFragment, getString(R.string.menu_home_label));
        return true;

    } else if (id == R.id.menu_calender) {

        CalenderFragment calenderFragment = new CalenderFragment();
        beginFragmentTransaction(calenderFragment, getString(R.string.menu_company_calender_label));
        return true;

    } 
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

** There are no errors in logs.

Also I have added mapview in first fragment and the second fragment contains calenderview.If needed I'll post the whole code here, but it just contains location service and some api calls that are triggered on button click.

The logs show this  **E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!** I'm searching for it.

Comment: can you please post the code

Comment: how did you migrate your project to androidx ?

Comment: I created a new project and selected use androidX artifacts

Comment: theres no need to paste the code paste the imports at the top of the class. i think you are using some lib version which are supported with android (not androidx)

Comment: @faiizii yes ,there was one such library. Will replace it .Thanks!

Comment: @Neha you said some API calls and location services calls are triggered onClick() may be API calls could be a reason for ANR

Comment: Actually the onClick() is not getting invoked as the view is taking much time to load ,so I don't think the API is the cause

Comment: @Neha that means HomeFragment is talking to much time to load?

Comment: no, even the drawer activity takes time

Comment: that's because in onCreateview() you're setting HomeFragment() may be that's the issue other looks fine to me use this for https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250819/7271231

Answer (score 0):

To fix the **E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!** error, I think you need `<uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"> </uses-library>` in your Manifest file.

As for the app is not responding error, I think your problem might be that you are requesting user information without the necessary permissions. Otherwise, I'd try to run the app in debug and see which line (or section of code) your code is getting stuck executing.

Comment: I have granted all the permissions I need for the app. Also added <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"> </uses-library> to manifest but still it shows the same error in logcat and app seems to stuck a bit

Comment: Glad to hear that isn't the problem.. Have you figured out where in your code it slows down when debugging?

Comment: No, not yet. I replaced the libraries which were using android.support ,and now the app seems to respond quite fast but still lags sometimes.