# ClassCastException: Fragment1 cannot be cast to Fragment2

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working on an Android app with a BottomNavigationBar and a FrameLayout. I have different fragments for every item of the BottomNavBar.
I'm trying to send datas from my MainActivity to one of them fragment using
`Fragment2 fragmentClass = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragLayout);`
(fragLayout is the ID of my FrameLayout.

But when I run my project, I get the following error in the LogCat :

> .ClassCastException: com.example.Fragment1 cannot be cast to com.example.Fragment2

What am I doing wrong? The Fragment2 is the active one when this code is running, so why does it say it cannot be cast to Fragment2 ?

Comment: ... because it's a `Fragment1`. And I would imagine they do not stand in an (valid) inheritance relationship.

Comment: How and when are you switching to `Fragment2`?

Comment: I'm switching of fragment when I click an item of the BottomNavBar. When I clicked it, it switches fragment and then run my code to send the datas to the fragment.

Comment: So you're still in `onNavigationItemSelected` when you try to send data to `Fragment2`?

Comment: Basically, onNavigationItemSelected, I call fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(Fragment2).commit(); and then I call a function with Fragment2 fragmentClass = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragLayout);

Comment: Related: [Android FragmentTransaction commit When?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246479/android-fragmenttransaction-commit-when)

Comment: I've tried with the link you've sent but I'm getting the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of searches, I've found the solution to my problem. I just used
`Fragment2 fragmentTwoClass = (Fragment2) fm.getFragments().get(1);`
instead of
`Fragment2 fragmentTwoClass = (Fragment2) fm.getFragmentById(R.id.fragLayout);`